# asking about the concept of a title

Tags: phrase-meaning

I was wondering if some one could help me with the title 'evolutionary baptism' in a book called "Before Atlantis" by Frank Joseph on 20 million years of human and pre-human cultures. I want to know what exactly the title stands for? Does it suggest the evolution of all the views towards the subject? Thank you.

Comment: The concept of "The lost city of Atlantis" is not exclusive to English.  If you know what Atlantis is, then your guess what "Before Atlantis" means is as good as any native speaker.   I suspect the question is off topic, but if you add more detail why you find this confusing (and some more information about the book) perhaps we can answer you.

Comment: Dear Andrew, thanks a lot for your answer.I was started thinking that no one would answer me. you are right. maybe I was not that clear about my problem, which is the word "baptism" in the title  "evolutionary baptism" (the book first chapter title). The book is on human evolution from the early time to present. I want to know if the word "baptism" in the title means  "the views towards the issue" or "the first experiences".

Comment: Well, again the concept of "baptism" is not exclusively, or even *originally* English.   If you know what *evolution* is, and you know what a *baptism* is, then your guess at the title is as good as mine.  :)

Comment: Oh, I got you. Thanks a zillion. It really worked. :))

Answer (score 1):

The title of chapter 2 in his book '**Evolutionary Baptism**' postulates that human evolution included one or more extensive periods where human progenitors were aquatic ... living in water - the reference to baptism.

OED on origin of baptism:

> Middle English: from Old French baptesme, via ecclesiastical Latin
>   from ecclesiastical Greek baptismos ‘ceremonial washing’, from
>   baptizein ‘immerse, baptize’

And from a review of the whole book:

> Further investigating the evolutionary branches of humanity, he
>   explores the mounting biological evidence supporting the aquatic ape
>   theory--that our ancestors spent one or more evolutionary phases in
>   **water**--and shows how these aquatic phases of humanity fall neatly into place within his revised timeline of ancient history.

[book review](https://www.bookdepository.com/Before-Atlantis-Frank-Joseph/9781591431572)

Comment: Very comprehensive great answer. What you said is quite true. Thanks a lot.